# Adjust the width of WP Customizer site preview iframe

Tags: wordpress

I am creating WP Customizer options for a theme I am developing. I am having trouble with the site preview iframe.

My site's original width on desktops is 1170px. On my MacBook 13 inch's Retina display, when I open my site in WordPress Customizer by going to Appearance > Customize from the WordPress Dashboard,  the width of site is reduced to 980px as it appears in the site preview iframe. Therefore, the customizer UI shows only the tablet (width < 981px) version of the website.

Is there any way I can resize the site preview iframe? So that it shows the full desktop version in customizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the size settings are defined inside wp-admin/css/themes.css

So to override them you can use [customize_controls_print_styles](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/customize_controls_print_styles)

So add this to your theme **functions.php** (so now you can mess with the settings)

```
    function my_customizer_responsive_sizes() {

    $mobile_margin_left = '-240px'; //Half of -$mobile_width
    $mobile_width = '480px';
    $mobile_height = '720px';

    $tablet_margin_left = '-540px'; //Half of -$tablet_width
    $tablet_width = '1080px';
    $tablet_height = '720px';

    ?>
    <style>
        .wp-customizer .preview-mobile .wp-full-overlay-main {
            margin-left: <?php echo $mobile_margin_left; ?>;
            width: <?php echo $mobile_width; ?>;
            height: <?php echo $mobile_height; ?>;
        }

        .wp-customizer .preview-tablet .wp-full-overlay-main {
            margin-left: <?php echo $tablet_margin_left; ?>;
            width: <?php echo $tablet_width; ?>;
            height: <?php echo $tablet_height; ?>;
        }
    </style>
   <?php
   }

add_action( 'customize_controls_print_styles', 'my_customizer_responsive_sizes' );
```

And here is one more [helpful link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/223684/how-to-adjust-the-device-preview-sizes-used-in-the-wp-4-5-customizer) for you.
Have fun :)